# ArchUnit - ensure method parameters are annotated

Tags: java, annotations, archunit

I'm trying to write an ArchUnit test rule, which should ensure that interfaces annotated with `@ComponentInterface` annotation have method parameters annotated with `@Input` annotation.
Like this:

```
ArchRule rule =
        methods()
            .that()
            .areDeclaredInClassesThat()
            .areInterfaces()
            .and()
            .areDeclaredInClassesThat()
            .areAnnotatedWith(ComponentInterface.class)
            .should()
            .haveRawParameterTypes(
                allElements(CanBeAnnotated.Predicates.annotatedWith(Input.class)));
```

The interface looks like this:

```
@ComponentInterface
public interface AdminComponent {
  void login(@Input(name = "loginString") String loginString);
}
```

But the test fails with an error like this:
`Method < com.some.package.AdminComponent.login(java.lang.String)> does not have raw parameter types all elements annotated with @Input in (AdminComponent.java:0)`

How should the rule look like to work properly in this case?

P.S. After doing some debug, it turned out that *haveRawParameterTypes* checks if parameter types (classes) are annotated, not the method parameters itself. So it looks at *String* class and finds out, that it is not annotated with *@Input*. Good to know, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can't find something about parameters neither frankly.. strange.. maybe it's missing.

Comment: It seems this is currently not possible. See https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/113 for the relevant issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always fall back to the Reflection API:

```java
ArchRule rule = methods()
    .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areInterfaces()
    .and().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(ComponentInterface.class)
    .should(haveAllParametersAnnotatedWith(Input.class));

ArchCondition<JavaMethod> haveAllParametersAnnotatedWith(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass) {
  return new ArchCondition<JavaMethod>("have all parameters annotated with @" + annotationClass.getSimpleName()) {
    @Override
    public void check(JavaMethod method, ConditionEvents events) {
      boolean areAllParametersAnnotated = true;
      for (Annotation[] parameterAnnotations : method.reflect().getParameterAnnotations()) {
        boolean isParameterAnnotated = false;
        for (Annotation annotation : parameterAnnotations) {
          if (annotation.annotationType().equals(annotationClass)) {
            isParameterAnnotated = true;
          }
        }
        areAllParametersAnnotated &= isParameterAnnotated;
      }
      String message = (areAllParametersAnnotated ? "" : "not ")
          + "all parameters of " + method.getDescription()
          + " are annotated with @" + annotationClass.getSimpleName();
      events.add(new SimpleConditionEvent(method, areAllParametersAnnotated, message));
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the information is meanwhile available (but not added to the fluent API yet) -> https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/pull/701

You can achieve it with e.g. a custom `ArchCondition`

```
methods()
  ...
  .should(haveParametersAnnotatedWith(Input.class))

// ...

private ArchCondition<JavaMethod> haveParametersAnnotatedWith(
  Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType
) {
  return new ArchCondition<JavaMethod>(
    "have parameters annotated with @" + annotationType.getSimpleName()
  ) {
    @Override
    public void check(JavaMethod method, ConditionEvents events) {
      method.getParameters().stream()
        .filter(parameter -> !parameter.isAnnotatedWith(annotationType))
        .forEach(parameter -> events.add(SimpleConditionEvent.violated(method,
          parameter.getDescription() + " is not annotated with @" + annotationType.getSimpleName())));
    }
  };
}
```